# How to get out a value outside of objective function of multistart (MS) of Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have a multi-start `fmincon` code. One variable needs to be determined: `u0`. Inside `ObjectiveFunc` there is a variable, `Parameter` I need to output when running multi-start, so I am trying to output a parameter that changes inside an objective function. I wrote a simple example below.

How can I output the value of the `Parameter` inside `Func(u0)` below when running `run(ms,Prob,big start)`?

```
ObjectiveFunc = @(u0) Func(u0);
gs = GlobalSearch; ms = MultiStart(gs); opts = optimoptions(@fmincon);
Prob = createOptimProblem('fmincon','x0',1,'objective',ObjectiveFunc,'options',opts);
u0_ini_range = 0.1:1:20;
[u0_iniGrid] = ndgrid(u0_ini_range); 
W = u0_iniGrid(:);
bigstart = CustomStartPointSet(W);
[u0_OptVal Delta_u0] = run(ms,Prob,bigstart);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
function Delta_u0 = Func(u0)
Parameter = randn(1);
Delta_u0 = u0+Parameter;
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what the question is. If `Delta` is a function of `u0` can you not use the code within your objective function (or write a new function) to calculate it again once `u0` has been found? Or do you just not want to do that calculation one additional time?

Comment: What does "in an arbitrary fashion" mean? Are you using random number generation?

Comment: Yes there is randn inside the function that changes it, though it is also function of u0. Any comments?

Comment: How complex is `HBM1_SlipSolution02hbm3Fcn`? Could you provide it, along with `Xst_rig`, to make the code runnable? The problem (and potential solution) is made more complex due to the use of `randn` – are you sure that it's a good idea to use it within an optimization procedure like this? You do realize that calls to `randn` will vary every time the objective function is evaluated by each of the multiple `fmincon` instances?

Comment: HBM1_SlipSolution02hbm3Fcn is actually very complicated and Xst_rig=1 is a constant. I have like 20 parameters to run the function and I need to put entire code so it would be very messy if I try to put it here. But you can think HBM1_SlipSolution02hbm3Fcn as a simple function. The thing is that, is there a way to get a parameter out of HBM1_SlipSolution02hbm3Fcn when run with Multi-Start, run(ms,Prob,bigstart)? 
I can keep recording it in a text file but it will slow the code down a lot. Hope there is a trick to this without slowing the code down. 
Yes randn will change I need to do it.

Comment: I created an example above. Can you check it horchler?

Comment: Anyone else has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to solve this issue. None of them are pretty. The problem is confounded due to the use of `MultiStart`, which runs multiple instances simultaneously, only one of which returns the global optimum. This means that the last evaluation of your objective function (and it's call to `randn`) isn't necessarily the relevant one.

Here's one way to accomplish this with `persistent` variables. First, you objective function need to look something like this (here `Delta` is your `Parameter`):

```
function [z,Delta_u0_Opt]=HBM1_SlipSolution02hbm3Fcn(u0)
persistent Delta idx;
if isempty(idx)
    idx = 0; % Initialize persistent index
end
if nargout > 1
    % Output Delta history 
    Delta_u0_Opt = Delta;
    z = (u0-Delta).^2;
else
    % Normal operation
    idx = idx+1;
    Delta(idx) = randn; % Save Delta history
    z = (u0-Delta(idx)).^2;
end
```

Then run your setup code as before:

```
ObjectiveFunc = @(u0)HBM1_SlipSolution02hbm3Fcn(u0);
u0_ini0 = 0;
gs = GlobalSearch;
ms = MultiStart(gs);
opts = optimoptions(@fmincon);
Lowbound = 0.1;
Xst_rig = 1;
Upbound  = 20*Xst_rig;
Prob = createOptimProblem('fmincon','x0',u0_ini0,'objective',ObjectiveFunc,...
                          'lb',Lowbound,'options',opts);
u0_ini_range = 0.1:1:Upbound;
[u0_iniGrid] = ndgrid(u0_ini_range); 
W = u0_iniGrid(:);
bigstart = CustomStartPointSet(W);
[u0_OptVal,fval1] = run(ms,Prob,big start);
```

Then extract your `Delta` value:

```
[fval2,Delta_u0_Opt] = HBM1_SlipSolution02hbm3Fcn(u0_OptVal)
Delta_u0_Opt = Delta_u0_Opt(fval1==fval2)
```

The main problem with this solution is that the entire history of `Delta` must be retained via constantly appending to a vector. And it requires that the function value of the solution, `fval1`, uniquely match only one of `fval2`. The solution could probably be optimized a bit and the last issue resolved by saving more state history and clever use of an output function. I have no idea how or if this would work if you decide to turn on `UseParallel`. As you can see, this optimization scheme is not at all designed for what you're trying to get it to do.

Finally, are you sure that it's a good idea to use random values in the way that you are for this kind of optimization scheme? At minimum, be sure to specify a seed so results can be replicated. You might consider creating your own global optimization method based on `fmincon` if you want something more straightforward and efficient.

Comment: Thank you Horchler. It is a good idea to use persistent variables, though I need to try and see if the performance is reduced largely. 
Yes I am just using the randn to generate some numbers for a response, this works better for convergence, as compared to starting with any constant value. 
But why isn't the u0_OptVal in [u0_OptVal,fval1] = run(ms,Prob,big start) matching the Delta_u0_Opt(find(fval1==fval2))? I can't see where the accuracy of that value is being lost...
Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand your question. `u0_OptVal` and `Delta_u0_Opt` are two completely different variables.  `u0_OptVal` is the optimal `u0` value that minimizes your objective function. `fval1` is the value of the objective function for `u0_OptVal`. `Delta_u0_Opt` is the `Delta` value that corresponds to (and which was used to calculate) `u0_OptVal`. I just simplified the code a bit to use logical indexing instead of `find`. Also `fval2(fval1==fval2)` should equal `fval1`.

Comment: whoops you are right I got confused about it. I will try the performance of this tonight and hopefully it will be good. Thank you a lot... :))